# ReceiveMessage does not work with abp.signalR

Tags: typescript, signalr, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm using abp.signalR but I've encountered problem-related to ReceiveMessage event, I wanna know once the message is received I tried below code but nothing happened :\

```
this.chatHub.on("ReceiveMessage", (username: string, message: string) => { 


});
```

**Web console screen shoot:**

[image]

**My back-end code:**
Do I need to add more code to the backend ?

```
namespace HealthMapControlPanel.ChatAppService
{
   public class MyChatHub : Hub, ITransientDependency
    {
         public IAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }

    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public MyChatHub()
    {
        AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("getMessage", string.Format("User {0}: {1}", AbpSession.UserId, "the message that has been sent from client is"+message));
    }
        public async Task SendToUser(string msg, long userId)
        {
            if (this.Clients != null)
            {
                await Clients.User(userId.ToString()).SendAsync("Send", msg, "From Server by userID ", Context.ConnectionId, Clock.Now);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new UserFriendlyException("something wrong");
            }
        }


        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        Logger.Debug("A client connected to MyChatHub: " + Context.ConnectionId);
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        Logger.Debug("A client disconnected from MyChatHub: " + Context.ConnectionId);
    }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because you are subscribing the `"ReceiveMessage"` on the client and on the server you are doing `.SendAsync("Send");`

You should change on the client to:

```js
this.chatHub.on("Send", (username: string, message: string) => { 
});
```

Or on the server:

```cs
await Clients.User(userId.ToString()).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", msg, "From Server by userID ", Context.ConnectionId, Clock.Now);
```

**Update**:

```js
this.chatHub.on("getMessage", (username: string, message: string) => { 
});
```

Comment: Close, but it should be the `"getMessage"` instead of the `"Send"`.

Comment: @aaron yeah, will change the answer.